# Reading about tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I'm working on trying to understand tensor products and I read this [article](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/the-tensor-product-demystified). Playing with some examples I took $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{R}^3$ and now I know that this has a basis $$\{e_i \otimes e_j \mid 1 \le i \le 2, 1 \le j \le 3\} = \{e_1 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_1 \otimes e_3, e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_3 \}.$$ Now what they are claiming is that for example $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}5\\ 6\\ 7\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}5\\ 6\\ 7\\ 10\\ 12\\ 14\end{pmatrix}$$ but I don't really understand this. What does this assignment mean in terms of the bases?

Comment: This is also a fine read: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tensor products are bilinear (i.e., $v\otimes(w_1+w_2)=v\otimes w_1+v\otimes w_2$ and $(v_1+v_2)\otimes w=v_1\otimes w+v_2\otimes w$), we can calculate:
$$\begin{align*}(e_1+2e_2)\otimes(5e_1+6e_2+7e_3)&=e_1\otimes(5e_1+6e_2+7e_3)+2e_2\otimes(5e_1\otimes 6e_2\otimes 7e_3)\\
&=5e_1\otimes e_1+6e_1\otimes e_2+7e_1\otimes e_3+10e_2\otimes e_1+12e_2\otimes e_2+14e_2\otimes e_3.
\end{align*}$$
Writing this in column notation gives your equation.